# Find out all java code places where a blocking operation happens

Tags: java, asynchronous, jvm, netty

In our *Netty* application. We are moving all blocking calls in our code to run in a special `backgroundThreadGroup`.

**I'd like to be able to log in production the `threadName` and the `lineNumber` of the java code that is about to execute a blocking operation. (i.e. sync File and Network IO)**

That way I can grep for the logs looking at places were we might have missed to move our blocking code to the `backgroundThreadGroup`.

Is there a way to instrument the JVM so that it can tell me that?

Comment: I doubt there's any foolproof method (unless you have a very narrow definition of "blocking"), but a good start might be to find methods that throw InterruptedException.

Comment: Even class loading can trigger a blocking operation. That’s completely outside your control. And what do you gain by putting the code in a special thread group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by a "blocking operation".

In a broad sense, any operation that causes a voluntary context switch is blocking. Trying to do something special about them is absolutely impractical.

For example, in Java, any method containing `synchronized` is potentially blocking. This includes

- `ConcurrentHashMap.put`
- `SecureRandom.nextInt`
- `System.getProperty`

and many more. I don't think you really want to avoid calling all these methods that look normal at a first glance.

Even simple methods without any synchronization primitives can be blocking. E.g., `ByteBuffer.get` may result in a page fault and a blocking read on the OS level. Furthermore, as mentioned in comments, there are JVM level blocking operations that are not under your control.

In short, it's impractical if not impossible to find *all* places in the code where a blocking operation happens.

If, however, you are interested in finding particular method calls that you believe are bad (like `Thread.sleep` and `Socket.read`), you can definitely do so. There is a [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) project specifically for this purpose. It already has a predefined list of "bad" methods, but can be customized with your own list.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called BlockHound, that will throw an exception unless you have configured BlockHound to ignore that specific blocking call

This is how you configure BlockHound for Netty: https://github.com/violetagg/netty/blob/625f9d5781ed85bfaca6fa4e826d0d46d70fdbd8/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/Hidden.java

(You can improve the above code by replacing the last line with     builder.nonBlockingThreadPredicate(
p -> p.or(thread -> thread instanceof FastThreadLocalThread)); )

see https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound
see https://blog.frankel.ch/blockhound-how-it-works/

I personally used it to find all blocking call within our Netty based service.
Good Luck